# Are there rules to using argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

When using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), how do I decide if something should be a positional argument, an optional argument, or a subcommand?

Comment: First, you decide what you want.  Next, you use `argparse`.  It's all up to you.

Comment: are there rules or best practices or something?

Comment: Use positional arguments for things that are required.  Use optional arguments for things that are not required.  Unfortunately, I don't know what you mean by "subcommand".

Comment: There aren't any rules.  But there are lots of examples, both in the `argparse` documentation (also the tutorial), and other SO questions.

Comment: Is there a usage first then code to produce that usage tutorial? Because I am getting confused when looking at the code first and not seeing a lot of examples of how the usage rules look.

Comment: @zondo Subcommands are essentially positional parameters that can have their own set of arguments and options. Git is one of the more common examples of a command with subcommands: `git status`, `git commit`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **positional** argument is typically *required*.  For example, if your program always needs to be passed a file to read, that file would be a **positional** argument.

An **optional** argument is, unsurprisingly, *optional*.  This might be an argument that can have a sane default (ie your program defaults to running on port `8080` but can accept other ports) or it might be a flag to turn on optional behavior (ie a `verbose` flag).

A **subparser** is typically used when you want to add a whole suite of different commands to a single script.  Perhaps your script can either read or write files, and the `read` and `write` operations expect various flags that don't overlap.  In this case, it would make sense to have a subparser for the `read` operation and a subparser for the `write` operation to simplify the parsing of those flags.

Most simple programs will want to stick with positional and optional arguments: you'll typically know when you actually need to use a subparser.

Here's a (very contrived) example program that uses all three:

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("filename", help="Filename to interact with")
    p.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true", help="Turn on verbose mode")

    subparsers = p.add_subparsers(title="Commands", dest="command")

    read_p = subparsers.add_parser("read", help="read from FILENAME")

    load_p = subparsers.add_parser("load", help="load from FILENAME")
    return p.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
```

And here's its help text:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] [-v] filename {read,load} ...

positional arguments:
  filename       Filename to interact with

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  Turn on verbose mode

Commands:
  {read,load}
    read         read from FILENAME
    load         load from FILENAME
```